# MongoDB wont connect to Python app in Kubernetes

Tags: python, mongodb, kubernetes, pymongo, kubernetes-helm

I have a python app that needs to connect to mongodb statefulset in kubernetes
I made a chart for my app and mongodb as a dependency using helm.
when the data needs to be written to the DB it send this error code:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed., full error: {'operationTime': Timestamp(1629805756, 1), 'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Authentication failed.', 'code': 18, 'codeName': 'AuthenticationFailed', '$clusterTime': {'clusterTime': Timestamp(1629805756, 1), 'signature': {'hash': b'\xde\x1e\t\x93:H\xd1\x9b\x9b\x15\xacu@S\xe9\x02\xd6#`\xae', 'keyId': 6999961677823213573}}}
```

The python configs for mongo:

```
from flask import Flask,request,render_template,jsonify
from pymongo import MongoClient
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
MONGODB_URI = os.getenv('MONGODB_URI')

app = Flask(__name__)
client = MongoClient(MONGODB_URI)
db = client.calocalcdb
collection = db.calocalc_collection
users = db.users
```

The mongo URI is in a secret file and the application should get it via env variable.
the program fails on this line:

```
user_id = users.insert_one(user)
```

When i try to echo $MONGODB_URI from the application pod it returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In your depoyment yaml you need something to map the secret to the environment variable; something like:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        env:
          - name: MONGODB_URI
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: <secret name>
                key: <secret name>
```

Comment: no success..
I thinks maybe it has something to do with username and password I honestly have no idea by now..